# inplace quick radix sort implementation

Tags: c++, sorting

I am reading about binary quick sort algorithm at following link

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr02/cs226/lectures/radix.4up.pdf

```
quicksortB(int a[], int l, int r, int w)
{ 
   int i = l, j = r;
   if (r <= l || w > bitsword) return;
   while (j != i)
   {
     while (digit(a[i], w) == 0 && (i < j)) i++;
     while (digit(a[j], w) == 1 && (j > i)) j--;
     exch(a[i], a[j]);
   }
   if (digit(a[r], w) == 0) j++;  //** question here.**
   quicksortB(a, l, j-1, w+1);
   quicksortB(a, j, r, w+1);
}
```

My question why is additional check after `while` loop is provided. Request to give an example when and why this condition is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when all of the elements in the partition have the same `digit(a[...], w)`?

When that happens, after the `while (j != i)` loop, `j` will point at the last element of that partition, and so `quicksortB(a, l, j-1, w+1)` will leave that element out, and `quicksortB(a, j, r, w+1)` will sort a range with one element.

In this particular case, though, you need to put all the elements with the same leading digit into one partition so that the first `quicksortB()` call will sort them.  When you do that, the second `quicksortB()` will get an empty partition and do nothing, which is safe.  That's what the `if` statement you highlight accomplishes.

In other words, that `if` statement basically says "Ok, radix sort did nothing at this level, so let's try again with at the next digit with all the elements in one partition."

If you didn't do that, then the element you left out would fail to get sorted properly, since you've only partitioned by the digit of interest in the radix sort.